# How can I disable IPv6 stack use for IPv4 IPs on JRE?

Tags: java, jvm, ipv6, jvm-arguments

As you can see on below screenshots, eclipse and Android SDK Manager (and other Java programs) are trying to connect to a IPv4 Internet IP via IPv6 TCP/IP stack while Proxifier (a proxy manager program, nevermind) can not support that.

[image: Eclipse failure in connecting to the Internet][image: Android SDK Manager failure in connecting to the Internet]

How I can disable IPv6 in Java?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I wanted to use this for some program I hadn't control for running that Java app so ended with this `_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` environment variable. (read about _JAVA_OPTIONS [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javaexe.html#JAVAOPTIONS))

If you are using Windows, just run this command on Windows cmd:
`setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Thanks to Jason Nichols for reminding this JVM argument :)

Comment: Thanks Ebrahim!! after I issued the command in Windows 8 command line, restarted Eclipse, the error from server side "Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine" disappeared! Many thanks!!

Comment: good find. it never occurred to me that an application could possibly use the v6 stack when clearly the destination host is a v4 system. sick.

Comment: This is because of such stupidity that some people end up disabling IPv6 _entirely_ from their whole operating system.

Comment: Agreed. Just to mention this just changes the preference AFAIK and doesn't disable whole thing, it seems Carlos answer below does that however :)

Answer (score 46):

Did you try (from the command line)

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

or (from your code)

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe a bit late but for me neither solution worked. So I included this option as it is stated [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/390840/how-does-one-get-tomcat-to-bind-to-ipv4-address):

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true
```

But also the followingI added line to the end of the file /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

And

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

as it is explained [here](https://pario.no/2011/12/09/disable-ipv6-on-ubuntu-11-10/). In order to check that ipv6 is disabled just execute:

```
ip a | grep inet
```

Comment: you, Sir, made my day! Finally able to start Java Springboot Tomcat App on tcp4 Port 8090 (by defalut it was started on tcp6 Port 8090). Thanks!

Comment: Well the answers did not work for me and I wasted a lot of time to find out the final solution And that is the aim of stackoverflow right?. Really appreciated but no need thanks!