# Address is invalid on local machine [on windows 8 only]

Tags: java, windows-8

I want to check the status code of request to url but getting code

```
java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine or port is not valid on remote machine
```

here is my code

```
public static boolean linkExists(String URLName){
        URLName = "http://www.google.com";
        try {
          HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
          HttpURLConnection con =
             (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLName).openConnection();
          con.connect();
          System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
          return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {           
           return false;
        }
  }
```

stack trace

```
java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:203)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:290)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:995)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:849)
    at com.sls.lms.test.utilities.Utilities.linkExists(Utilities.java:70)
    at com.sls.lms.test.report.ReportTest.checkReportData(ReportTest.java:70)
    at com.sls.lms.test.report.ReportTest.CheckReportForGST(ReportTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:138)
    at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.start(JUnit4TestRunner.java:81)
    at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.run(JUnit4TestRunner.java:69)
    at org.testng.TestRunner$1.run(TestRunner.java:682)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1012)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRunJUnit(TestRunner.java:713)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:614)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1338)
    at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1307)
```

Comment: DNS problem I guess. Can you ping google from console? Is there any proxy, firewall?

Comment: ping www.google.com is working fine

Comment: provide stack trace please

Comment: how to get stack trace??

Comment: Are you behind any proxy ? Just check your browser settings, if they use any proxy.

Comment: ok stack trace added :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that this issue is caused by Java attempting to use an IPV6 address, when either your OS doesn't support it, or is not set up properly to handle it.

You can force Java to use an IPV4 address with the following property:

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Comment: I am using windows 8. how to force Java here? I tried same above code it works fine on windows 7

Comment: the java.net.preferIPv4Stack *should* work on all platforms, however, I'm not a Windows user, so I can't test it there - sorry.

Comment: found the command to set the above property on windows... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850655/how-i-can-disable-ipv6-stack-use-for-ipv4-ips-on-jre

Answer (score 1):

One thing I notice is that your URL connection has not been used... you haven't called connect(). I would be disappointed in the error message if that fixed your problem, but you probably can't get a response code until after you have made a request.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html

Comment: used conn.connect() it is throwing the same exception

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me with **Eclipse**. Definitely take Nikolay's advice and check if you have a firewall running. Any forum post I have seen related to this exception have been related somehow to this situation.

Comment: I am using it in netbeans in selenium testing.

Answer (score 0):

Close all java programs and open up run (<kbd>winkey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) or just search run if you have a start button like me, and write `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` in. :)

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this problem but just shutdown my antivirus and phew it is working, this has to do with the antivirus blocking the ports.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem. 
i have windows8 64 use netbeans7.4.
my antivirus is kaspersky. the solution is to
turn of your antivirus or make the antivirus pause then run the code it will work

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem.My anitvirus is kaspersky.the solution for this is,open kapsperksy->settings->Anti virus protection->moinitored ports->select

Answer (score 0):

I got this message when trying to open Socket with IPv4 address and Port 0. May be you should check the port used when you see this message.

Answer (score 0):

I was creating a socket connection to a remote server by providing IP address and port number of the server. Was able to ping the server and was also able to telnet to the port. So no connectivity issues, still got same error posted in the question.
I made a silly mistake of passing in an empty string to creating the socket instance. It is useful to use debug mode to point out such mistakes.