# Can't start Tomcat with Eclipse: "Address already in use"

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I can't start my tomcat server. I was trying almost everything. Switching location doesn't help, as a server location. I'm on Windows 8.

Here I post my console errors:

```
 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
 INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in
 production environments was not found on the java.library.path:
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Users/Krzys/Desktop/eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/Krzys/Desktop/eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/jre/bin;C:/Users/Krzys/Desktop/eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/jre/lib/amd64;;C:\Users\Krzys\Desktop\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:21 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
 WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
 property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Lab5' did not find a matching property.
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
 INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
 SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:406)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:658)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:96)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:175)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:393)
    ... 17 more

 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
 SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:658)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:406)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:96)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:175)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:393)
    ... 17 more

 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
 INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
 SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8009
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:406)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:658)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
 Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:96)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:175)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:393)
    ... 16 more

 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
 SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:658)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8009
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:406)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:96)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:175)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:393)
    ... 16 more

 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
 INFO: Initialization processed in 1271 ms
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
 INFO: Starting service Catalina
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
 INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.39
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
 INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Krzys\Desktop\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\docs
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
 INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Krzys\Desktop\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\examples
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@737d54dd')
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
 INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Krzys\Desktop\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\host-manager
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
 INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Krzys\Desktop\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\manager
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
 INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Krzys\Desktop\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\ROOT
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
 INFO: Server startup in 3028 ms kwi 23, 2013 3:53:24 PM
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
 SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8080]:
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:96)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:175)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:766)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:712)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
 INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
 INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
 INFO: Stopping service Catalina
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
 INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
 INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
 INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
 kwi 23, 2013 3:53:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
 INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

---

After hit on stop of Tomcat I get this error in the console:

```
 kwi 23, 2013 4:27:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
 SEVERE: Catalina.stop:
 java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:499)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:458)
```

Comment: The other errors you are seeing when stoppint Tomcat have been answered previously - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105357/address-is-invalid-on-local-machine-on-windows-8-only

Comment: possible duplicate of [Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat Server at localhost are already in use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064733/several-ports-8005-8080-8009-required-by-tomcat-server-at-localhost-are-alre)

Answer (score 12):

By default, Tomcat is configured to start on port `8080` but you have something already bound to that port. It is likely to be another instance of the Tomcat web server.

`Address already in use: JVM_Bind :8080` in the log means that your machine already has a service listening on port `8080`. Find it, either with [`netstat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) (command line tool) or [TCP View](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897437) (graphical tool), shut it down, then restart Tomcat. It should get past that error.

Alternatively, configure Tomcat in Eclipse to start on a different port by double clicking on the `Tomcat vx.x Server at localhost` line in the *Servers* tab and changing *all* the ports shown on the right hand side of the window that appears to something different.

Comment: Ok. It starts. I copied a simple 'Hello world' example, into eclipse. But it still shows 'HTTP Status 404'. I'm fighting with it from yesterday. I'm sure that code i good because i was starting it in my school and it works.

Comment: Check the path in the `Modules` page in Eclipse (double clicking on the `Tomcat vx.x Server at localhost` line in the Servers tab and see there is another "page" on the main window). Eclipse has a habit of mapping web applications to the name of the context for example `http://localhost:8080/helloworld/` whereas you might want to have it mapped to `/` instead in Eclipse allowing you to type `http://localhost:8080/`.

Comment: `it still don't work` is not very useful. _What exactly doesn't work?_  Really, this question is answered as Tomcat now starts under Eclipse. This latest problem is probably just a mis-configuration of Tomcat. I suggest asking a new question including specific code and detailed information about everything you have so far including the Tomcat log and links to any tutorials you are trying to follow.

Comment: @user2071550 common problem is running skype when tomcat is configured to bind on port 8080 (which is default config). quick fix: if you have skype running, stop it, start tomcat and then start skype again. long fix: reconfigure booth tomcat and skype.

Answer (score 3):

Just simply change all ports like :Tomcat admin port,Http/1.1 and Ajp/1.3

Example
Tomcat admin port :8005 change to 8004,
Http/1.1          :8080 change to 8081,
Ajp/1.3           :8009 change to 8008.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem with you and I resolved this after reboot my PC. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

It says the port number 8009 is already occupied by some other process running on your OS.

if the service running on 8009 is needed you could change the connector configuration in server.xml to something like below :

> Connector port="8089" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the instance thats using the port is another tomcat and you are unable to shut it down. Force close java runtime may help.

Answer (score 0):

simply..

start > search for "services" you will see the tomcat service is running stop it.

re-run your project now and hope you won't face any difficulty