# Address family not supported by protocol family - SocketException on a specific computer

Tags: java, sockets, socketexception

In an app which I have programmed, I have a **java.net.SocketException** on a specific computer:

> java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol family: connect

This specific computer runs Windows 7 32 Bit and is connected to the internet through Local Area Connection (Ethernet).
The app runs correctly on other computers, with Windows 7 and Windows 8, connected through Local Area Connection or through Wi-Fi, so I am actually not sure that the problem is programmatic.
I have tried to check the protocols of the Local Area Connection, but I didn't see any problems.
Can someone please help me understand what is the problem? Why is this exception thrown?

Comment: Try any network packet monitoring software like Wireshark

Comment: And what do I have to see there?

Comment: You are trying to connect to some port,right?? Check if the TCP packets were received on that port and what was the response received

Comment: I am actually trying to work with HTTP, so it is port 80.

Comment: You monitor the traffic on 80 after you run your code

Comment: Does my filter have to be "portmap.port == 80"?

Comment: yes. your filter should be

Comment: It claims that:
Header checksum: 0x0000 [incorrect, should be 0x15ff (may be caused by "IP checksum offload"?)]

Comment: http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/11682/checksum-errors-when-browsing-the-internet. Read this

Comment: I don't understand much... I see here (http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Offloading) the following instructions:
In Windows, go to Control Panel->Network and Internet Connections->Network Connections, right click the connection to change and choose 'Properties'. Press the 'Configure...' button, choose the 'Advanced' tab to see or modify the "Offload Transmit TCP Checksum" and "Offload Receive TCP Checksum" values.

I found this, but I don't known what are the wanted values for these settings.

Comment: OK, fixed it. It all seems OK but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try to check whether the spy program called "RelevantKnowledge" is installed. Its uninstallation helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: It really could be the problem.

Comment: I observed the same issue with another malware named "PremierOpinion".

Comment: I don't know where this "RelevantKnowledge" come from but when I try this answer, it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 26):

For me Java option `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` did the trick

Answer (score 20):

1. Open command prompt (windows start button, type cmd in search)
2. Click top left of command prompt, click properties, enable quick edit mode
3. Copy: `setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`
4. Right click on command prompt, should paste
5. Hit enter. That easy!

Comment: I added it to Azure's 'App settings' in the portal and it worked!

Answer (score 5):

It may be a few things:

- Anti-virus blocking the connection. If you have an anti-virus running on that computer, try disabling it for a test.
- Java 7 trying to use IPv6 to connect: if you have Java 6 on the computers where it works and Java 7 where it fails, try disabling IPv6 in Java on the computer where it fails (instructions [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850655/how-i-can-disable-ipv6-stack-use-for-ipv4-ips-on-jre))

Comment: It uses the same Anti-Virus as my computer does, and it runs the most updated version of Java 7.
Please look at the comments to my question.

Comment: See the bullet item about disabling IPv6 in Java 7.

Comment: No, it's Java 7 in all of the computers.

Comment: It may be worth trying disabling IPv6 on that computer for a test. It will ate least exclude it from the list of possible culprits.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 6, try to change to java 7. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this helped me :

Anti-virus blocking the connection. If you have an anti-virus running on that computer, try disabling it for a test.

Open command prompt (windows start button, type cmd in search)
Click top left of command prompt, click properties, enable quick edit mode
Copy: setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Right click on command prompt, should paste
Hit enter. That easy!