# Springboot embedded tomcat binds to IPV6

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I am working on a rest api using springboot, I am facing small issue when I try to deploy the jar it auto binds to ipv6 which we do not want, I know I can use external tomcat. But just for the sake of learning I was wondering if it is possible to force it to bind to ipv4 instead?

Thanks
Sajid

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question, but professional server administration. These are off-topic. Either way, it is not related to embedded systems. Read the tag decriptions before adding them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable IPv6 stack use for IPv4 IPs on JRE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850655/how-can-i-disable-ipv6-stack-use-for-ipv4-ips-on-jre)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `server.address` in your `application.properties` file to control the network address to which you app will bind.