gRPC Application only listening for IPv6 Address
I am trying to run a Java gRPC Application on an Oracle Cloud Instance but it keeps listening only for IPv6 address
$ netstat -tulp | grep 16507
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6       0      0 [::]:16507              [::]:*                  LISTEN      210081/java
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 16507
tcp6       0      0 :::16507                :::*                    LISTEN      210081/java

However the same application on windows listen for both IPv4 & IPv6.
> netstat -ano | findstr :16507
  TCP    0.0.0.0:16507          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       40124
  TCP    [::]:16507             [::]:0                 LISTENING       40124

I even tried explicitly mentioning grpc.address = 0.0.0.0 as well as switching my gRPC Spring Boot dependency from "net.devh:grpc-server-spring-boot-starter" to "io.github.lognet:grpc-spring-boot-starter" but still nothing has changed. Has anybody faced something similar?

Have you tried -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true ? E.g. this Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70960853/14072498

Thank you very much @RoarS. now it is listening on IPv4

java -jar -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true appname.jar

Fixed it.
