# Disable IPv6 in Docker container from Java

Tags: java, docker, ipv6, docker-java, spotify-docker-client

I need to disable IPv6 when starting a Docker container from Java code. Using the command line, it is as follows:

`docker run --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1 ...`

- Is it possible to do the same but using Java with Spotify's [docker-client](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client)?
- As alternative solution... would it be possible to do with [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable IPv6 stack use for IPv4 IPs on JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850655/how-can-i-disable-ipv6-stack-use-for-ipv4-ips-on-jre)

Comment: @juanlumn My question is related with the use of Docker from Java.

Comment: @MichaelHampton My target application is not Java, in fact it is a browser in a Docker container. I want to change the settings of that container using a Java library (docker-client or docker-java) but it seems it is not possible. At least I didn't find how, for that reason I'm asking.

Comment: It doesn't appear that either of those clients supports setting sysctls on a container. Consider submitting an issue, or better, a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do that with our docker-java-api (see Wiki and the linked blog post for details about it): https://www.github.com/amihaiemil/docker-java-api

In principle, it should be as simple as:

```
final Docker docker = new LocalDocker(...); //or new RemoteDocker(...);
final Container container = docker.containers().create(/*javax.json.JsonObject config*/);
```

Of course, you have to study the Docker API documentation in order to see what format the JsonObject should have (it should accept config about IpV 6 as well).

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this -

https://github.com/spotify/docker-client/blob/2966b5cad6568d3c1b23f8891fbecab110834785/src/test/java/com/spotify/docker/client/DefaultDockerClientTest.java

```
 final NetworkConfig networkConfig =
        NetworkConfig.builder().name(networkName).driver("bridge").checkDuplicate(true).ipam(ipam)
            .internal(false).enableIPv6(false).labels(labels)
            .build();
```